# Iterate over string without space as seperator in bash-shell

Tags: bash, shell, loops, sed, cut

I'm trying to parse some output of xmllint since hours, but I can't get it to work like i would need it.

Output of `"xmllint --xpath "//fub/@name" menu.xml"*`

> name="Kessel" name="Lager" name="Puffer " name="Boiler.sen"
>   name="Boiler.jun" name="HK Senior" name="HK Junior" name="Fbh"
>   name="Solar" name="F.Wärme" name="Sys "

Now I need to seperate all the names (inclusive spaces) and get them in to seperate variables.
My approach was this:

```
fubNames=$(xmllint --xpath "//fub/@name" menu.xml | sed 's/name=//g')
for name in $fubNames
do
    echo $name
done
```

but this does not workout because the for-loop seperates the string on spaces.
i need the names with spaces. (note: some names have a space at the end)

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
xmllint --xpath "//fub/@name" menu.xml | grep -o '"[^"]*"' | while IFS= read -r name; do echo "$name"; done
```

Comment: thank you, i marked this as accepted answer, because the loop is included in this one. could you explain the grep command maybe? i dont fully understand it.

Comment: `"[^"]*"`: match double quotes followed by any characters but not double quotes (`[^"]`). The star quantifier (`*`) means that the preceding expression can match zero or more times. Last matching character must be double quotes.

Comment: is it also possible to save that output to an array?

Comment: Try this: `mapfile array <<< $(xmllint --xpath "//fub/@name" menu.xml | grep -o '"[^"]*"')` and check array: `declare -p array`

Comment: this command creates an array but puts all lines in a single field.
after some further digging i used the "mapfile -t array < <(xmlllint ...)" syntax. now it works but i dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

***grep*** approach:

```
xmllint --xpath "//fub/@name" menu.xml | grep -Po 'name=\K\"([^"]+)\"'
```

The output:

```
"Kessel"
"Lager"
"Puffer "
"Boiler.sen"
"Boiler.jun"
"HK Senior"
"HK Junior"
"Fbh"
"Solar"
"F.Wärme"
"Sys "
```

---

`-P` option, allows Perl regular expressions

`-o` option, tells to print only matched parts